# for what layer need to write unit test?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, unit-testing, mstest

I am new to unit testing / TDD.  We are developing a web application with the following architecture:

1. MVC
2. WCF service layer
3. Business Logic Layer
4. DAL with EF

I have not done unit testing before but saw it in some projects so I have not a clear idea about it.

Should we write unit test for every method of every layer or these are specific to some layer ?

Secondly should we put one project and put all layers unit test in it ? I want to know how to manage unit tests for all layers in test project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for an all-agile shop and we do the following:

1. We start by writing UATs (User Acceptance Tests). For you this would be done through Cucumber + WatiN or something similar. They are written with business features in mind.

2. Next we write unit tests for the class(es) that we are intending to add. This means testing every single public method and all its logic branches. This pretty much applies to everything but the views.

3. For hairy code, we add integration-level tests that tie multiple classes to make sure they integrate correctly.

Some layers are not tested as the assumption that they "just work" is there (ie DBMS)

Usually your CI should run the unit tests first, then integration tests (if unit tests pass), and finally the UATs which are the slowest and only if integration tests pass

Comment: ,thanks a lot for these basic guidelines. Can you please also share some guidline on design like how to design classes, DAL, BL etc so that these can be better tested ? I am sorry for that basic asking but just because I m not aware and you are practicing it. 

Cucumber, WatiN are these best tings to adopt ?

Comment: The approach we take is "if it's to messy to test it, split it up into pieces". DAL we test by mocking/stubbing the methods and making sure that they are called the right number of times, and the right order, and with right parameters. Cucumber you should use for sure as it's easy for business people to write behavior in natural English. WaitN is not great but it's one of the few options you have there. Compared to other places, code that I write is in more classes with much fewer lines per class/method to ease testing.